# KKT conditions for minmax optimization

Tags: optimization

If I have a function of the form $V(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, and I want to perform $min_ymax_xV(x,y)$, given the constraint $x^2=1$, how can I write the KKT conditions to solve this problem? Thanks